# Accessing element of a JArray -without Foreach loop

Tags: json

I'm developing an application where I receive a JSON array from an API. It has only one object. How do I access it in a single line syntax without using forEach loop?

object is inside array

```
[{"fiscalPeriod":8,"fiscalYear":2018,"calendarStart":"2018-02-11","calendarEnd":"2018-03-10"}]
```

Comment: can you give us an example of the object please ?

Comment: [{"fiscalPeriod":8,"fiscalYear":2018,"calendarStart":"2018-02-11","calendarEnd":"2018-03-10"}]

Comment: Both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here some examples

```js
var arr = [{"fiscalPeriod":8,"fiscalYear":2018,"calendarStart":"2018-02-11","calendarEnd":"2018-03-10"}];

console.log(arr[0].fiscalPeriod); // logs '8'

console.log(arr[0].fiscalYear); // logs '2018'

console.log(Object.keys(arr[0])); //["fiscalPeriod", "fiscalYear", "calendarStart", "calendarEnd"]

console.log(Object.keys(arr[0])[2]); //logs "calendarStart"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one item in the array you can get it out like this:

```
var array = [{"fiscalPeriod":8,"fiscalYear":2018,"calendarStart":"2018-02-11","calendarEnd":"2018-03-10"}];
var obj = array[0];
```

That square bracket syntax with the 0 in it says: give me the first item in the array.